# Trigger to update Parent object field after a record is inserted/updated in child object?

Tags: apex, visualforce

**Updated**

There are two objects student_details__c and department__c.
department__c - contains name and no_of_students__c;
student_details__c contains name, department(lookup to department object).

when a student is inserted in a department, that respective department needs to increment the no_of_students__field,similarly when department is changed of a student from one dept to other then no_of_students__c needs to be incremented in the new department and decremented from the old department field.
no_of_student__c is the total count of students in respect to the department the belong to in each department object.

I have finally come up with this, it is working fine, now if anyone can help me with code optimization, it would help me great in the future.
Thanks

**Trigger**

```
trigger Test on Student_Details__c (after insert, after update,after delete) {


        studentupdatehandler studobj = new studentupdatehandler( ,trigger.old);
        if(trigger.isinsert)
        {
        studobj.afterinsert(trigger.new);
        }

        if(trigger.isdelete)
        {
        studobj.afterdelete(trigger.old);
        }

       if(trigger.isupdate)
       {
       studobj.afterupdate(trigger.new,trigger.old);
       }    
}
```

**Trigger Handler**

```
 public void afterupdate(student_details__c[] newstudentList ,student_details__c[] oldstudentList) {


         set<id> newDeptids = new set<id>();

         for(student_Details__c record: newstudentlist){

            newDeptids.add(record.Department__c);
            }


        list<department__c> newdeptlist = [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:newDeptids];

        toinsert(newdeptlist);

        set<id> oldDeptids = new set<id>();

        for(student_Details__c record: oldstudentlist){

            oldDeptids.add(record.Department__c);
            }

        list<department__c> odeptlist= [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:oldDeptids];

        toupdatedelete(odeptlist);  

}

Public void toinsert(department__c[] deptlist ){

        for(department__c dept : deptlist){

               if (dept.Name == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }
               else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }
               else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

            }                 
   update deptlist;      
        } 

Public void toupdatedelete(department__c[] odeptlist ){


        for(department__c dept : odeptlist){

               if (dept.Name == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                    }

                else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }
                else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

            } 



  update odeptlist; 
}




}
```

Comment: You should not write this trigger yourself. Just use **[declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**.

Comment: How does the observed behavior diverge from your requirements? Also you will have a significantly easier go of it if you use **[logic-less triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#Logic-less_Triggers)** (and other best practices).

Comment: Using triggers (and not roll ups), you'll need to do a bit more. First of all, you're always incrementing by one on any update. Next, if the genre is changed, the old genre's book count needs be decreased. Also, you need to handle deletes. Rollups are easier if the relationship is master-detail but that has implications. I'd recommend writing the trigger to get all the genre ids (similar to what you have but for trigger.old as well), and doing an aggregate query to get the actual counts.

Comment: Seems to me using a Master detail relationship would be appropriate here, then you could just use a standard roll up summary field

Comment: Also undeletes should not be ignored. You should fire on every event and apply the relevant criteria.